# Access value of NSTableView

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview

I need to access to values of my cell based TableView from another controller. I do this code in my main controller and the tableView is in a child controller.
Here is what I do but I'm getting nil ...

```
// First grab the tableView controller
let myTableViewController = self.children[0] as! MyTableViewController

// Now I want to access the first row to get values of the textFields
let firstRowView = myTableViewController.theTable.rowView(atRow: 0, makeIfNecessary: true)

//Let's try another way :
let firstView = myTableViewController.theTable.view(atColumn: 0, row: 0, makeIfNecessary: true)

//I can't do more because "firstRowView" and "firstView " are nil
```

[image]

What I want is an array that contains all string of the table like :

```
let array1 = ["Peter","Quinn","1","387","49"]
```

**EDIT :**

I tried with a **view base** tableView, it works, I can get the textFields in my array.
But if edit a textfield by clicking ont it (changing "Peter" by "Franck"), it doesn't work, the NSTextField disappears in the debug utility...

```
let firstRowView = myTableViewController.theTable.rowView(atRow: 0, makeIfNecessary: true)?.subviews // return the first TableView
let textFields = firstRowView!.map { $0.subviews } as! [[NSTextField]]
let texts = textFields.map {$0.first!.stringValue}

print(texts) // let array1 = ["Peter","Quinn","1","387","49"]
```

Why I doesn't work anymore if I change manually a text ?

Here is what "firstRowView" contains when I don't manually edit a cell :
[image]

And here is what "firstRowView" contains when I manually edit a cell and it crashed :
[image]

You can see the NSTableCellView is transformed into NSView and my textField has disappeared... (it's still there in UI of course...)

Comment: Can't you get the data from the datasource?

Comment: The data is set in the storyboard for now, I can (and I need) to edit the data directly by editing the cell with keyboard.

Comment: Are you planning to use a datasource or Cocoa bindings in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all never get data from the **view** (the table view), get it from the **model** (the data source array).

In macOS there is a very convenient way. Use Cocoa Bindings and a **view** based table view. Apart from the model there's almost no code needed.

- Create a model, a class inheriting from `NSObject` is mandatory to take advantage of Key-Value Coding

  ```
  @objcMembers
  class Person : NSObject {
      dynamic var firstName, lastName : String
      dynamic var age : Int
      dynamic var number1, number2 : Int

      init(firstName : String, lastName : String, age : Int, number1 : Int, number2 : Int) {
          self.firstName = firstName
          self.lastName = lastName
          self.age = age
          self.number1 = number1
          self.number2 = number2
      }
  }
  ```
- Declare a data source array

  ```
  @objc dynamic var people = [Person]()
  ```
- and populate it

  ```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      people = [Person(firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Quinn", age: 1, number1: 387, number2: 49),
                Person(firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Quinn", age: 1, number1: 387, number2: 49)]
  }
  ```

**That's the entire code.** Now do the bindings.

In Interface Builder first select the table view (the easiest way is to <kbd>⌃⇧-click</kbd> into the table view area and select ***Table View***), go to Bindings Inspector (press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd>) and bind the *Content* to `View Controller` and set *Model Key Path* to `people`.

[image]

Then select the text fields one by one – again <kbd>⌃⇧-click</kbd> on each text field in the table view and select ***Table View Cell*** – and bind the *Value* to `Table Cell View` and set *Model Key Path* to `objectValue.<property>` for example

[image]

That's all. All changes in the table view (for example editing a field) are synchronized with the model. If you want to get the first name of the second entry just write

```
let secondFirstName = people[1].firstName
```

Comment: thank you, I have never used cocoa binding but it seems to be great.